# Scale and rotate tool vs. selection tool in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, resize, selections, rotate

I just started learning Adobe Illustrator. The first three tools I have learned are selection tool, scale tool and resize tool. I see that we can resize and rotate a vector object with selection tool. First select the object then take the mouse near any of the 8 corners of the bounding box outline.

Now my question is if we can both resize and rotate any object with selection tool then what is the need of Scale tool and Resize tool at all?

Answer (score 2):

The Scale and Resize tool allow you to be precise in your changes. By double clicking on their icon a window with different options will appear and you can set you changes with specific parameters.

**Rotate Tool**

[image]
[image]

**Scale Tool**

[image]
[image]

By the way, you can achieve the same result that you would get by using those tool applying a transform effect to your object, and the transformations remain editable. 
You'll find this effect from the top navigation bar in **Effect/Distort & Transform/Transform**. The following window will appear and you can set your different modifications.

[image]